# Scrolling Page to top in SilverChildBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_up),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),

        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              expandedHeight: 255,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Container(
                  height: 255,
                  width: 380,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("images/PromotionBanner.png"),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill),
                  ),
                  child: Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset(0, -60),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "images/PromotionLabel.png",
                      width: 331,
                      height: 67,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) {
                  return announcementCard(
                      titleText: announcementList[index].titleText,
                      image: announcementList[index].image,
                      containImage: announcementList[index].containImage,
                      innerContent: announcementList[index].innerContent,
                      time: announcementList[index].time,
                      date: announcementList[index].date);
                },
                childCount: announcementList.length,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
```

So this is my code and I want to display **FAB** when the user reach to *end of page* and on press of **FAB** *scroll back  to top*.

This can be done in **ListView.builder** by using ScrollController but how to achieve same in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code I tried.
(Because there is no asset 'announcementCard' when I tested, I changed codes)

- using scrollcontroller when reach to bottom of list, show floating button
- when reach to top of list, hide floating button
- when click floating button, go to top of list

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool isEndOfList = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.atEdge) {
        if (_scrollController.position.pixels == 0) {
          // you are at top position
          setState(() {
            isEndOfList = false;
          });
        } else {
          // you are at bottom position
          setState(() {
            isEndOfList = true;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: isEndOfList
          ? FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _scrollController
                  ..animateTo(
                    0.0,
                    curve: Curves.easeOut,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                  );
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_up),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            )
          : null,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            floating: false,
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 255,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Container(
                height: 255,
                width: 380,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("images/PromotionLabel.png"),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill),
                ),
                child: Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(0, -60),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "images/PromotionLabel.png",
                    width: 331,
                    height: 67,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 50,
                  child: Text('1111'),
                );
              },
              childCount: 20,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware about controller inside custonScrollView.